# What is the problem in this code, it is showing total is undefined

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double getTotal(double prices[], int size); //Declaration of a function.


int main(){

    double prices[] = {5.63, 4.21, 75, 6.14, 2.4};
    int size = sizeof(prices) / sizeof(prices[0]);

    double total = getTotal(prices, size); // Call a function

    cout << "$ " << total << '\n';

    return 0;
}

double getTotal(double prices[], int size) //Define a function.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        total += prices[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

I want to run this code but it is showing error while defining a function. It is showing that total is undefined.

Comment: You should post the exact error message, as text. But anyway - `total` is indeed not defined in `getTotal` function. You should add something like `double total = 0;` in the beginning of the function in order to define to local variable.

Comment: A side note: better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: Also you shouldn't spam tags. This question has nothing to do with specific c++ version, or visual c++.

Comment: FYI -- `#include <numeric>` -- `double getTotal(double prices[], int size) { return std::accumulate(prices, prices + size, 0.0); }`

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `total += prices[i];`, what do you think should happen each time that code runs? Why? "It is showing that total is undefined." Do you understand what this means? Do you think it is wrong? What do you think should be the definition of `total`, and why?

Answer (score -1):

You should declare "total" variable in getTotal function as well.

In C++, variables are local to scope surround by { and }.
You can't use total variable defined in main function.

```
#include <iostream>

double getTotal(double prices[], int size); //Declaration of a function.

int main(){

    double prices[] = {5.63, 4.21, 75, 6.14, 2.4};
    int size = sizeof(prices) / sizeof(prices[0]);

    double total = getTotal(prices, size); // Call a function

    std::cout << "$ " << total << '\n';    

    return 0;
}

double getTotal(double prices[], int size) //Define a function. 
{

    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        total += prices[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

There is one more issue.
In getTotal function, opening curly brace { is not included in compile, because it's after the // symbol, which makes all letters that come after it on line into comments.

And using **namespace::std** is bad practice.
Use **std::cout** intead.
It's against the principle of namespace isolation.

Comment: @Mat, I updated answer. Is this all right?